# How to compare the time-complexity of an optimized algorithm with that of the original?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, performance

I had an algorithm with time-complexity of $O(h\times w)$, knowing $h$ is the height and $w$ is the width of an image being processed (or a simple matrix of size $h\times w$).

I managed to reduce the range that the algorithm process. So rather than dealing with $h\times w$ elements, it is dealing with $n\times m$ elements, where $n<h$ and $m<w$.

To recapitulate the optimization :

- Time-complexity of old algorithm is $O(h\times w)$
- Time-complexity of new algorithm is $O(h) + O(n\times m)$

Now my question is : how to express this time complexity optimization in terms of $h$ and $w$ ? is it a real optimization ?

Comment: I changed your former title "**How to compute the time-complexity of an
optimized algorithm relative to the original algorithm ?**". The
reason is that it did not seem to make sense. The two complexities can
be compared, but they are computed indpendently. --- --- Did you make sure
that dealing with a smaller number of elements did not change the cost
of dealing with one element?

Comment: sorry, but I am unable to answer your question ... I don't know the meaning of *cost* or how to compute it ?

Comment: *Cost* is a generic term that you can replace by *time*, *space*, *energy* of whatever other cost measure you are considering when doing complexity analysis. So here, you may read it as "time complexity to process one element".

Comment: It depends.  How does $n$ relate to $h$?  What's the smallest it could be, and the largest it could be?  Same for $m$ and $w$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "complexity optimization".

A proper way to compare complexities is by considering their
ratio, which is defined up to a constant factor. Considering the difference makes no sense, as there is always
the invisible constant factor lurking around, invisible but not
negligible.

However your problem here is that you have several variables, not the
same in both variants of your algorithm, and no indication of how they
relate. If you do not say precisely how $n$ and $m$ relate to $h$ and
$w$, there is nearly nothing that can be done.

Given That all you know is that $n<h$ and $m<w$, the best you can say
is that  $n\times m<h\times w$. But they may differ by a constant
additive term or by a constant multiplicative factor, which does not
change the complexity.

So the best you can say is that $O(m\times n)\subseteq O(h\times w)$,
short of more precision on how $n$ and $m$ relate to $h$ and
$w$

Thus $O(h)+O(m\times n)\subseteq O(h)+O(h\times w)$.

But $O(h)\subseteq O(h\times w)$, because both are linear in $h$ and
the first is constant in $w$ while the second is linear.

Hence you get: $O(h)+O(m\times n)\subseteq O(h\times w)$.

All we know is that the **complexity is not worse than before**.

But that should not worry you too much. You seem to have the wrong
vision of complexity, when asking:

> is it a real optimization ?

Your optimizations aim at improving performance in your range of
applications.

**Complexity does not measure performance but scalability.** A
  constant multiplicative factor of ten zillions does not change the
  complexity but has a drastic effect on performance. The matrix
  multiplication algorithm that have the best complexity are never
  used because they have abysmal performance. You have to consider
  huge matrices for them to be any use.

Furthermore, raw complexity on arbitrary measure of the size of the
problem may have little practical meaning in some cases. The relevant
size for some complexity analyses may be the number of occurences of a
specific feature of the problem input, rather than the length of the
problem in number of symbols. Some exponential algorithms are
routinely used without problems because the feature causing the high
complexity is actually rarely used, independently of the input size.

Your modification of the algorithm may be a real optimization, that
may give you an algorithm ten times faster, but this may not show in
complexity analysis.

This is why it is sometimes useful to do precise cost analysis. But
that is more difficult since you must account for the different costs
of different elementary operations (which is not required for
complexity analysis).

A possible way to assess your optimization is benchmarking, rather
than tedious theoretical counting.

Your question did not say whether you were considering worst case or
average complexity. I did not ask because my remarks apply in both
cases.

Note: The fact that the algorithm has better performance, with the same
worst case complexity does not imply that the average complexity was
improved.

Comment: I can add that $n$ is almost equal to $w$ BUT $m$ is inferior to $h$ sometime by half, sometime by more.

Comment: As I said, constant factors will not change the complexity. You have to give a precise function of $u(h)$ which is an upperbound for $m$, i.e. $\forall h, m<u(h)$, and which grows less than any linear function. But improving the complexity is probably not your real worry.

Comment: the relation between $h$ and $m$ (or even an upperbound) is very impredictible. So even if the worst-case time-complexity may be the same. the running performance can be better ?

Comment: @OSryx YES, the running performance can be better  It can be a zillion times better without changing the complexity. Suppose you do not trust your computer, so you do every computation twice on the same input to double check the first answer against stray cosmic rays. Your algorithm will be twice as slow. But your complexity will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that, before your optimization, your algorithm had the same worst- and average-case complexity, which is why it was easy to consider.

The change in asymptotic complexity really depends on how $n$ and $m$ relate to $w$ and $h$. If they are reduced by a constant factor, then your asymptotic complexity is not improved. If they are some root or logarithmic function, then your complexity has improved.

"[If the asymptotic complexity is the same,] is this a real optimization?"

Yes! Anything you can do that improves the average case without (or rarely) hurting the worst case, even if the improvement is only by a constant factor, makes the algorithm more useful in real world problems. 4x might be a constant improvement, but if you can make me run 4x faster, I'll be ecstatic.  As @babou states in his answer, the asymptotic complexity is only useful in studying how the running time changes with a change in input size.

Comment: Interesting ... $m$ is near $w$ but $h=c\times n$. So the time complexity in worst case is not optimized since constant $c$ can be equal 1. But the time complexity in average maybe $c=1/2$ !! I have to consider to compute the tc in average case. What is the symbol ? It is not big-o ? UPVOTE

Comment: It is still big-oh. Big-oh can be used in discussion of any asymptotic complexities, but you should mention the exact use (if it is not clear from context). For instance, in parallel algorithms you must specify the work and time complexities. Look at a discussion of quick sort for an example of an average-case vs. worst-case complexities.

Comment: I do not see why "*before [the] optimization, the algorithm had the
same worst- and average-case complexity*". The question does not even
say what kind of complexity is being considered. I do not see either
why you assume (seemingly) that the optimizations improved the average
case complexity.

Comment: @babou The question implies that the unimproved algorithm always takes $O(w \times h)$; hence, the average- and worst-cases are the same. I assume that the time is improved in at least some cases, because otherwise (s)he would not have asked the question.

Comment: Your last comment is meaningless. Having complexity $O(w×h)$ is an
asymptotic property of the function, which says absolutely nothing
about the time of computation for a specific input size. What it says
is that if it is worst case complexity, then the function giving the
worst time to be expected grows as $w×h$ when $w$ and $h$ grow to
infinity. It does not say that that all computations on that input
size cost the same time. The use of the word "always" makes no
sense. I am afraid you do not really understand the meaning of the
Landau "big O" notation, and of worst case complexity.

Comment: @babou You can be afraid if you want, but I understand just fine; please consider my second paragraph. Average- and worst-case complexities differ all the time, as they do in practically every stochastic algorithm (ex. QuickSort).

Comment: OK. Assuming it makes sense, where does the question imply "*that the
unimproved algorithm always takes $O(w×h)$*"? Then, how does this imply
that "*the average- and worst-cases are the same*"? I am not concerned
at all with the new algorithm.

Comment: @babou The first sentence *very* clearly implies that. I do not understand why this is your point of contention with my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26139/discussion-between-kittsil-and-babou).

Comment: @OSryx See [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use) for a quick introduction into which Landau symbol to use when.

Comment: I agree with @babou. The question does not specify what kind of "complexity" they mean. With the usual worst-case default the assumptions of this answer don't follow. The second and third paragraph, however, don't need this assumption and are valid.

Comment: The chosen answer is an excellent explanation but it lacks one detail : how to read/pronounce each landau symbol.

Comment: @OSryx How to read/pronounce each Landau symbol. See [wikipedia: Bachmann–Landau notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations). This reference is also given in the [reference page](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use) given above by Raphael. More generally there is a [wikipedia page for Greek letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Letters). This said, both the question and the answer used only $O(\ldots)$, that should not raise pronunciation problems.